# Prolog - Add list numbers

Tags: list, prolog, addition

I am trying to solve some prolog exercises in order to learn the language and i have problem adding the numbers in a prolog list.

For example i have the list [1,2,3] and i want to have as output number 6.

I wrote this code but it is not working.

```
list_adder([H|T],S):- S is H + T.
```

can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
list_adder([ ],0).
list_adder([X|L],Sum) :- list_adder(L,SL), Sum is X + SL.
```

Comment: Remember that prolog works in a recursive manner. You are attempting to add the first element off the list to the rest of the list. I.E. in a list of [1,2,3] you are attempting to add 1 + [2,3]. The function needs to recurse through the rest of the list.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `H + T` in the example is matched with `1 + [2, 3]`, which doesn't mean anything. You should process the `[2, 3]` further, as shown in Fourth's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_adder(L,X),
        list_adder(L,[],X).

list_adder([],L,X) :-
        length(L,X).
list_adder([N|R1],L1,X) :-
        length(L,N),
        append(L1,L,L2),
        list_adder(R1,L2,X).
```